# How to get the social hub working?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

Since I started playing this game last week, I've never got a positive message for the social hub. It always says it's not available. I'm using the Steam version of the game.

In the meantime I've created a Square Enix account and linked it with my steam account because I thought that this could be necessary, but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: same with me. no fix?

Comment: @Shackrock: not so far

Comment: Does not solve your issue, but you don't miss out. It is just leaderboards, which I think is kinda useless in a Singleplayer Game, but hey, each to their own.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a wireless connection you could try using a wired connection and see if the problem persists.

The only other alternative I can suggest to the above is to re-install the game, but copy the saved game files beforehand if you don't want to lose all your data.

If you have Steam installed on your C:\ drive, the saved game files will be located in the following directory:

> `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\SleepingDogs\Data`

or another similar location.

Comment: Thanks for your troubleshooting instructions, but I believe this is a problem that has been plaguing a lot of PC users. Square Enix has acknowledged its existence but has yet to come up with a proper solution for this. I doubt they ever will, or even know what the root cause is.

Comment: Well, that sucks :(

Comment: @yassarikhan786: thanks, but I'm with deutschZuid on this matter. I'm on wire and not gonna re-install the game for a network connectivity or authentication or whatever issue.

Comment: No worries, I thought it may help. I guess you'll have to wait for Square Enix to properly address the problem.

Comment: @yassarikhan786 - Unlikely to happen considering all content for the game has been released.  The game is basically in the maintenance period, where only the most critical bugs will be fix, most won't be.

Comment: @Ramhound - Hmmm, that's unfortunate :(